# RUBY: Selenium webdriver, setup to download pdf files instead of opening them

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

When I goto a page with a pdf, it opens in a viewer instead of downloading.

How can I fix my code to download the file into the specified folder?

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require 'pry'

#driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

download_prefs = {
  prompt_for_download: false,
  default_directory: 'folder/pdf_downloads'
}

plugin_prefs = {
  always_open_pdf_externally: true
}

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_preference(:download, download_prefs)
options.add_preference(:plugins, plugin_prefs) 
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options

# Goto Login Page (file)
url="file:///page.html"
driver.navigate.to url
element = driver.find_element(id: 'formsubmit')
element.submit

sleep 5
# Goto info page
info_url = 'https://webapp.domain.com/Secure/info'
driver.navigate.to info_url

sleep 5

# Download pdf at link
elements = driver.find_elements(css: "#ar-pdfreport a")
link = elements.first.attribute("href")
driver.navigate.to link
```

Comment: People from WATIR team is maintaining this ruby selenium binding. So I included the watir tag.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.link.click` ?

Comment: Also you are adding prefs the "new" (non-depricated way). I have not gotten that to work to override the default download path on mine no matter what I've tried. So are you able to test the ability to download any file to that directory instead of the default one? If the download-prefs aren't working, then maybe the plugin-prefs isn't working either?

Comment: Link.click works the same way. Opens the pdf in viewer, but less efficient since I would need to click a drop down menu first.

Comment: What’s the new way?

Comment: I tried Watir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247385/watir-wont-download-pdf-only-opens-in-viewer  same issue