# Watir: How to set `chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments`

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I am trying to set the options for Watir with chrome driver, but can no figure out how to set:

`chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments` to true or false.

What would the pref variable be to set this?

`Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs}`

Comment: Did the updated solution in https://stackoverflow.com/q/66247385/1200545 not address this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42927095/4072371

```
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally" => true}
Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {prefs: prefs}
```

Make sure you are using a String for the prefs key